# Unknown entity: com.boto.SpringHibernatee.entity.Employee;

Tags: java, spring, spring-orm

it is workin when i call `.setAnnotatedClasses(Employee.class)`
but when i call `.setAnnotatedPackage("com.boto.SpringHibernatee.entity")` it throws unknown Entity Exception

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionfactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(getproperties());
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(datasource);
    sessionFactoryBean.setAnnotatedPackages("com.boto.SpringHibernatee.entity");

    return sessionFactoryBean;
}


@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionfactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(getproperties());
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(datasource);
    sessionFactoryBean.setAnnotatedClasses(Employee.class); 
    return sessionFactoryBean;
}
```

Comment: Can you put the code in a nicer way (here)? Is weird with the picture approach and appears incomplete.

Comment: Check your package structure. And the package 'com.boto.SpringHibernatee.entity' should always be complete lower case. Rename 'SpringHibernate' to 'springhibernate'

Comment: The obvious question that comes to mind is: "is the package of Employee really com.boto.SpringHibernatee.entity". I guess not. But you haven't posted the relevant code, so it's impossible to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setPackagesToScan

```
@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionfactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(getproperties());
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(datasource);
    sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan( new String[] {"com.boto.SpringHibernatee.entity"});

    return sessionFactoryBean;
}
```

Comment: thnaks .. it working now.. But do u hvae idea why setAnnotiatedPackage() did not work?